# Adding If statement with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two txt files

```
CHROM   POS REF ALT BOB_123
chrX    67  G   A   0.025
chrX    302 A   AC  0.068
chrX    677 C   CCT 0.599

CHROM   POS REF ALT BOB_89
chrX    678 T   TC,C    0.063,0.895
chrX    650 T   C   1
chrX    1438    A   G   0.999
```

I need to split the biallelic SNPs like this

```
CHROM   POS REF ALT BOB_89
chrX    678 T   TC  0.063
chrX    678 T   C   0.895
chrX    650 T   C   1
chrX    1438    A   G   0.999
```

I wrote the script that works for file 2, but for file 1 gives an error. I guess this is because it has no split(","). How to add an If statement since I want to run all the scripts in batch and I do not know which of them have biallelic SNPs and which ones do not?

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
df = pd.read_csv("infile", sep='\t', index_col=False)
df_new = (df.set_index(['POS', 'CHROM', 'REF']) 
   .apply(lambda col: col.str.split(',').explode())
   .reset_index()
   .reindex(df.columns, axis = 1))
df_new.to_csv("outfile", sep='\t', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `col.str.split().explode()` is giving errors on columns that are not strings. So a solution could be to force all to str when reading file, then cast to numeric what is possible to convert to numeric with [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), but I'm not a pandas expert so this may be not-optimized.

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import SYS
df = pd.read_csv("infile", sep='\t', index_col=False, dtype=str)
df_new = (df.set_index(['POS', 'CHROM', 'REF'])
    .apply(lambda col: col.str.split(',').explode())
    .reset_index()
    .reindex(df.columns, axis = 1))
df_new = df_new.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')

df_new.to_csv("outfile", sep='\t', index=False)
```

Comment: may be this is not necessary? df_new = df_new.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')

Comment: It depends, I can suppose you'll need those values as numeric in order to do some computational tasks, but if this is not the case, sure, it can be omitted.